# How do i prepare mysql statement with many left join?

Tags: php, mysql

Please can i get some help, I dont know why this prepared statement doesn't work

```
prepare("SELECT articles.id_article, articles.name_article, articles.object, articles.photo, articles.category_category_id, articles.date_entred articles.views, category.name as category, auteur.name as auteur  
    FROM articles
    LEFT JOIN category 
        ON category_id = category_category_id
    LEFT JOIN auteurs
        ON id_auteurs = auteurs_id_auteurs
    WHERE articles.id_article = ?
    GROUP BY articles.id_article
    ", [$id], __CLASS__);
```

Comment: whats the full code?

Comment: What driver are you using? What does error reporting show? Normally you bind the value with the `bind` or `execute` function.

Comment: What is your aim? what is the error you get?

Comment: Thank you guys I just miss coma between those column "articles.date_entred articles.views"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:
`articles.date_entred articles.views`

Should be:
`articles.date_entred, articles.views`

Also `entred` should probably change to `entered`... Unless `entred` is a foreign word I don't know

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I will be more carful next time.